# How to add an auto increment column in an existing delta table in databricks

Tags: pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks, delta-lake

In Databricks
I have a existing delta table,
In which i want to add one more column, as
Id so that each row has unique id no and
It is consecutive (how primary key is present in sql).

So far I have tried converting delta table to pyspark dataframe and have added new column as

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window as W
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df1 = df1.withColumn("idx", F.monotonically_increasing_id())
windowSpec = W.orderBy("idx")
df1 = df1.withColumn("idx", F.row_number().over(windowSpec)).show()
```

I tried writing it back to delta table,

```
df.write.mode("append").format("delta").save(location/db.tablename)
```

It writes back but the data values
After querying is null for the new id column.
I read, overwrite mode will erase all previous data.
How can I bring the column id data to delta table and keep incrementing the id column when data gets inserted?

I am trying to achieve adding a autoincrement column for delta table.
The databricks runtime is 7.3.

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to achieve adding a autoincrement column for delta table. The **databricks runtime is 7.3**.

from [official document](https://docs.databricks.com/release-notes/runtime/10.4.html#identity-columns-support-in-delta-tables-is-now-generally-available),

Identity column feature is **supported for runtime version 10.4 and later** not for below runtime 10.4

**Altering table by adding new Column with Identity is also not supported**

To achieve your goal first you have to migrate from `runtime 7.3` to `runtime 10.4` **And create new table with [identity column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-create-table-using) and then [copy the data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/delta-copy-into) from first table to new table.**